# position of image is not changing while changing position of uiimageview controller

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview

i am making an app in which i am placing an imageview in uitableview cell but when i am chnaging my image view position on story board and then run the application but that image is not appearing according to the position of uiimage view below i am adding screen shots 
[image: here is my story board]

[image: and this is my output]

and below is my tableview cell for row at indexpath code

```
    static NSString *tableviewidentifier = @"cell";
   __block  tablecellTableViewCell *cell= [self.activitiesTableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[tablecellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    }if(indexPath.row == [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1){

    }
     __block NSString *row = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];

    UILabel *valuedate = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:21];
    UILabel *msg = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:22];
    UILabel *date = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:23];
    UILabel *time = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:24];
    if([[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageRead"] intValue]==0)
    {

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(245/255.0) green:(245/255.0) blue:(245/255.0) alpha:1];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    }
    valuedate.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"offerTitle"];


    msg.text=@"How are you?";
    if(![[imagesDictionary allKeys] containsObject:row]) //if image not found download and add it to dictionary
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            NSString *img=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"offerPhoto"];// here i am getting image path
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:img];
            NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //in main thread update the image
                 [imagesDictionary setObject:image forKey:row];
                cell.imageView.image = image;
                cell.textLabel.text = @""; //add this update will reflect the changes
                NSLog(@"loading and addig to dictionary");
            });
        });
    }
    else
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [imagesDictionary objectForKey:row];
        NSLog(@"retriving from dictioary");
    }


    date.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageDate"];
    time.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageTime"];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: create a new iboutlet for imageview and name it 'displayImageView' in .h file. Then use cell.displayImageView instead of cell.imageView. Hope this will solve your prob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think u are setting the default image of cell not the image view which is present in custom cell

in the above code `cell.imageView.image` is the default image of cell. Change the name of the image view which is present in custom cell to some different name for example `profileImageView` then set the image something like

```
cell. profileImageView.image = myImage;
```

in the above code u are using the custom tableview cell's image view